# Dynamic component not loading inside patent component

Tags: angular-dynamic-components

I'm creating dynamic component based on it's type.

With the above structure, I created parent component which is `ParagraphComponent` and If you notice `ranges` is having a `type` so I wanted to create a `LinkComponent`.

**What's the Problem ?**

`LinkComponent` is created but not inside it's parent component, It
   is created outside of the `ParagraphComponent`.

```
<rc-paragraph><p>This is paragraph</p></rc-paragraph>`
<app-link>/index.htm</app-link>
```

But actually it should be like this,

```
<rc-paragraph>
    <p>This is paragraph <app-link>/index.htm</app-link></p>
</rc-paragraph>
```

Below is the code for rendering the component,

```
private renderReactiveContent(content, container: ViewContainerRef) {

    // resolve content['_type'] to factory
    var type: Type<any>;
    if (content instanceof Array) {
      type = this.contentMappings[content[0].type];
    } else {
      type = this.contentMappings[content.type];
    }
    if (!type) {
      return;
      // throw new ReferenceError(`No content mapping for type=${type}`);
    }

    const componentFactory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(type);
    const component = container.createComponent(componentFactory, container.length, this.injector);
    console.info('Component dynamically created ', component);

    // content lifecycle hook: notify of new values
    const cmpCreate = asContentCreate(component);
    cmpCreate.contentOnCreate(content);

    // render embedded content
    if (content && Object.keys(content).length > 0) {

      const cmpEmbeddable = asContentEmbeddable(component);
      if (cmpEmbeddable) {

        // render in the target element of ContentEmbeddable
        const childContainer = cmpEmbeddable.contentEmbeddable();

        Object.keys(content).forEach((key: string) => {
          const value = content[key];

          // XX: recursive rendering
          if (value instanceof Array) {
            value.forEach((v) => {
              this.renderReactiveContent(v, childContainer);
            });
          } else {
            this.renderReactiveContent(value, childContainer);
          }
        });

      } else {

        // fatal: embedded content must be hosted by ContentEmbeddable
        const cmpName = component.instance['constructor'].name;
        throw new TypeError([`Trying to render embedded content.`,
          `${cmpName} must implement interface ContentEmbeddable`].join(' '));

      }

    }
    component.hostView.detectChanges();
  }
```

What I'm doing wrong here, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How angular injects a view is that if your host is

```
<span #container><span>
```

Then It will inject it as

```
<span><span>
<your-injected-view></your-injected-view>
```

So when you are trying to inject to the parent, your parent is the host element and child element is injected next to it, instead of inside it.

How to solve it?
One way can be to make an element inside the parent a host element instead of making a parent container a host.

```
<parent>
 <span #container></span>
</parent>
```

So it will inject it as

```
<parent>
  <span></span>
  <your-injected-view></your-injected-view>
</parent>
```

It's always good to use `<ng-container></ng-container>` for injecting view and avoiding any side effects.